# After verify site ownership is it ok to remove html meta tag from index html file?

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, meta-tags, ownership, site-verification

we have verified our site ownership using HTML tag in index file of our website

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="your verification string">
```

we have added above tag in the head tag
we have successfully set meta tag & achieved our goal to activate search console
my question is for accessing search console in future should I need to remain meta tag in the index file **or**

**we can remove those tag from index file will work for me**

Comment: Why would you care whether or not that meta tag is in place?

Comment: what is the need of removing ?refer this site:https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en

Comment: meta tag left in a code will no harm us at all but for our knowledge, I need to understand once you verified you can remove or not.

Answer (score 7):

**After verifying site ownership, is it ok to remove the `<meta name="google-site-verification">` tag?**

No. If you want to remove it and remain verified, you'll need to use another form of verification.

[Reference](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en#:%7E:text=Search%20Console%20periodically%20checks%20if%20your,will%20expire%20after%20a%20certain%20grace%20period.)